# How to add arrow to cardview right side

Tags: android, cardview

I have rectangle Cardview

[image]

how to add to my cardview something as an arrow or triangle (it can be with no dot)

[image]

like as on the right side of this image?

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            ........
            android:text="asdasdasdsdasdaadsaasd"
             />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

color and text of cardview I'm applying via adapter and arrow color should be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a vector drawable of the required shape, bg_img.xml. You can use this [site](https://svg2vector.com) to create vector from an image. However, this is not always accurate, so once xml is generated you can try playing with it, to adjust.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportWidth="3276"
    android:viewportHeight="1840">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ED1C24"
        android:pathData="M0 0L2263.5 0L2264 2.5L3237.5 881L3276 913.5L3276 932.5Q3276 933.5 3271.5 933L2266.5 1840L0 1840L0 0Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#ED1C24" />
</vector>
```

Set this as background to your textView

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:backgroud="@drawable/bg_img"
      android:text="asdasdasdsdasdaadsaasd"/>
```